# Downloading multiple file as parallel in R

Tags: r, file, download

I am trying to download 460,000 files from ftp server ( which I got from the TRMM archive data). I made a list of all files and separated them into different jobs, but can any one help me how to run those jobs at the same time in R. Just an example what I have tried to do

```
my.list <-readLines("1998-2010.txt") # lists the ftp address of each file
job1 <- for (i in 1: 1000) { 
            download.file(my.list[i], name[i], mode = "wb")
        }
job2 <- for (i in 1001: 2000){ 
            download.file(my.list[i], name[i], mode = "wb")
        }
job3 <- for (i in 2001: 3000){ 
            download.file(my.list[i], name[i], mode = "wb")
        }
```

Now I m stuck on how to run all of the Jobs at the same time.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Please see the post "[Running multiple R scripts/sessions]" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367026/running-multiple-r-scripts-sessions) on StackOverflow. Basically, if you are looking into speeding up the process of downloading the files from the ftp server, downloading them concurrently might not be much faster than downloading them one-by-one.

You could always open a second console window in your R application.

Comment: Is this TRMM stuff from the same source that has some handy hints on downloading: http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/mirador/help.pl?helppage=checkoutoptions.shtml&helpmenuclass=help_checkout&keyword=TCC&startTime=1945-10-08&endTime=2013-05-28T07:20:22Z&CGISESSID=048f56f9faf60197cd152b661964b500&SearchButton=Search%20GES-DISC which includes download managers and custom tools?

Comment: just write a python script for this.

Answer (score 10):

Dont do that. Really. Dont. It won't be any faster because the limiting factor is going to be the network speed. You'll just end up with a large number of even slower downloads, and then the server will just give up and throw you off, and you'll end up with a large number of half-downloaded files.

Downloading multiple files will also increase the disk load since now your PC is trying to save a large number of files.

Here's another solution.

Use R (or some other tool, its one line of awk script starting from your list) to write an HTML file which just looks like this:

```
<a href="ftp://example.com/path/file-1.dat">file-1.dat</a>
<a href="ftp://example.com/path/file-2.dat">file-2.dat</a>
```

and so on. Now open this file in your web browser and use a download manager (eg [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) for Firefox) and tell it to download all the links. You can specify how many simultaneous downloads, how many times to retry fails and so on with DownThemAll.

Comment: hi I have access to high performance computing so I think downloading won't affect that much as well as the space of the disk. I don't mind putting them in parallel

Comment: How is high performance computing going to help? You need high performance NETWORKING between your machine(s) and the server which is on the other side of the internet. Your CPU is doing hardly anything except wait for some more bytes to come in on the ethernet port and then ask the disk controller to save them. Use a Download Manager as I suggest or the tools on the web site or maybe see if you can pay to have the data delivered on DVDROM.

Answer (score 7):

A good option is to use the `mclapply` or `parLapply` from the builtin `parallel` package. You then make a function that accepts a list of files that need to be downloaded:

```
library(parallel)
dowload_list = function(file_list) {
       return(lapply(download.file(file_list)))
   }
list_of_file_lists = c(my_list[1:1000], my_list[1001:2000], etc)
mclapply(list_of_file_lists, download_list)
```

I think it is wise to first split up the big list of files into a set a sublists, as for each entry in the list fed to `mclapply` a process is spawned. If this list is big, and the processing time per item in the list small, the overhead of parallelisation is probably going to make the downloading slower in stead of faster.

Do note that `mclapply` only works on Linux, `parLapply` should also work fine under Windows.

Comment: Hi I have tried your approach but some reason it does not work. I can't explain why? Well the download.file has to have argument of file name and destination so I fixed that and for parLapply in windows(I am using windows)need to define cluster (cl).. so I modified as follows

Answer (score 0):

First make a while loop which looks for all the destination file. If the current predefined destination file is in the existing destination file, the script creates a new destination file. This will create many destination files which correspond to each one downloading. Next, I parallel the script. If I have 5 cores on my machine, I will get 5 destination files on my disk. I can also use lapply function to do that.

For example:

```
id <- 0
newDestinationFile <- "File.xlsx"
while(newDestinationFile %in% list.files(path =getwd(),pattern ="[.]xlsx"))
{
    newDestinationFile <- paste0("File",id,".xlsx")
    id <- id+1
    download.file(url = URLS,method ="libcurl",mode ="wb",quiet = TRUE,destfile =newDestinationFile)

}
```