# Partitioning R script and/or R sessions (environment)

Tags: r, session, partitioning, environment

Well, I am curious about an issue, which would be helpful and time-saving, if not it's not the end of the world.

I researched a bit, but I could not find what I literally want. Also,
[Running multiple R scripts/sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367026/running-multiple-r-scripts-sessions)
I checked this link, but again it doesn't help me much.

The situation is that I have a big dataset (the test data I try to use has roughly 6.5m rows and 50 columns, I also have difficulty in implementing the dataset into R, I use now 60k rows for analysis and for statistical models. (I try to see how the data can be manipulated and understand its behavior, and hopefully I wish to integrate these models and manipulations all the stuff I did with the big dataset even if not all of 6.5 m rows, 1 2m is ok for me if I can).

Anyways, another big problem is my R environment. Since the data is so enormous, it requires diligence and big work. The code script is like 3500 rows and it's not even 15% of the work. The problem is by creating new datasets, assigning new models, model adequacy check, and new models, etc. all costs me a new stuff in environment, and my environment is like 750mb (the R session/profile). I hoped that I may decrease the size of the environment stuff (the profile) if I divide the R scripts or environments.

Any ideas would be great. Appriciated for any help.

Edit : After creating a clean script, and starting up with a clean environment, database implementation took place without an error. Just in case for ones who suffer this implementation issue like me. Not telling this is the only and exact way, though.

Comment: "my environment is like 750mb" which is rather small. Your question is not terribly clear and a bit rambling. I suggest you look into building a package (which would also force you to follow the functional programming paradigm and that could help with your cluttered global environment).

Comment: 6.5 million x 50 is not really enormous. If this already gives you troubles I'd suggest a quick trip to the electronics store to buy more RAM.

Comment: I agree, I've had single plot objects in size of multiple GB. When handling big data in R, you'll want at the very least 16GB RAM.

Comment: Well, in SQL database it's nothing, but i have difficulty implementing it in r, connecting to a db and reading the table gives an error, is it only about RAM ? Btw, its now 750mb,but like 10% of the work has been done, when it's completed it would be like 15 20 times greater I guess, could be relatively small again for ones who works with data in petabytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, I usually write scripts that produce a specific workspace, and then keep another script which contains pathing to all the scripts and to the saved workspaces.

Imagine this script:

```
## Dataset x
# Run script to create dataset x
source("pathtoscript.R")

# Save dataset x environment
save.image("pathtodatasetx.Rdata")

# Load dataset x environment
load("pathtodatasetx.Rdata")
```

This way I can quickly run and save an environment if I made any changes, or just load it into my current session.